# How to fetch records with exactly specified has_many through records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I feel like I have read all SO "has_many through" questions but none helped me with my problem.

So I have a standard has_many through setup like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_associations
  has_many :products, through: :product_associations
end

class ProductAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_associations
  has_many :users, through: :product_associations
end
```

IMO, What I want is pretty simple:

**Find all users that have a product association to products A, B, and C, no more, no less**

So I have a couple of products and want to find all users that are connected to **exactly** those products (they shouldn't have any other product associations to other products).

This is the best I came up with:

```
products # the array of products that I want to find all connected users for

User
  .joins(:product_associations)
  .where(product_associations: { product_id: products.map(&:id) })
  .group('products.id')
  .having("COUNT(product_associations.id) = #{products.count}")
```

It doesn't work though, it also returns users connected to more products.

I also toyed around with [merging scopes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) but didn't get any result.

All hints appreciated! :)

Comment: Your schema doesn't seem right at all -- so an order can only have one product?

Comment: It was just a contrived example. I updated the classes, hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from users
join product_associations on product_associations.user_id = users.id
where product_associations.product_id in (2,3)
and not exists (
  select *
  from product_associations AS pa
  where pa.user_id = users.id
  and pa.product_id not in (2,3)
)
group by product_associations.user_id
having count(product_associations.product_id) = 2
```

It does two things, find users with: 1) all the product associations and 2) no other product associations.

Sqlfiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee8e/5

It can be Railsified™ (somewhat) in to:

```
User.joins(:product_associations)
  .where(product_associations: { product_id: products })
  .where("not exists (select *
    from product_associations AS pa
    where pa.user_id = users.id
    and pa.product_id not in (?)
  )", products.pluck(:id))
  .group('product_associations.user_id')
  .having('count(product_associations.product_id) = ?', products.count)
```

Comment: Nope, has_and_belongs_to_many is different from has_many through.

Comment: For the record (pun intended), `has_and_belongs_to_many` is pretty much identical to `has_many through` under the hood.

Comment: *sigh* I will ignore the snarky "fake code" remark, alright? Your code doesn't work, still returns users with more than the two products.

Comment: apologies if I sounded snarky, long day :). I've updated the code, I believe it now works.

Comment: No worries. Your code works now! :) Turned out more complicated than I expected though...

Comment: It was more complicated that I thought at first too. I'd be as interested as anyone if there was a better way to approach this.